# How do i set the maxDate as the nthday to the current selected date in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery UI date picker in my website

I have a From and To fields and my requirement is after the user selects the From date the To field date picker should start from the From date and end after 14 days.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. [Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6NhbM/)

​

```
$​(document).ready(function() {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        minDate: 'today', 
        maxDate:'+1Y', 
        onSelect: function() {
            var minToDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var maxToDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            maxToDate.setDate(maxToDate.getDate()+14);
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minToDate);
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxToDate);
}});
    $("#to").datepicker();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var datepickersOpt = {
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+1Y",
}

$("#from").datepicker($.extend({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 14);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
    }
}, datepickersOpt));

$("#to").datepicker($.extend({}, datepickersOpt));​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYLpT/2/)